# Max Euclidean distance between two columns of a matrix in Matlab / Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, euclidean-distance

I need to calculate for a program the maximal euclidian distance of vectors that are put together in a matrix `A` in Octave.

What I have so far:

```
for i=1:n 
   for k=i:n+1
      C=A(:,i)-A(:,k);
      maxdiff=max(norm(C),maxdiff);  
   endfor
endfor
```

This is not working and I don't know why. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Define "not working". Please provide sample input, the output you receive, and your expected output.

Comment: The problem was in the code before, I found the mistake! Even though, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pdist`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) from the Statistics Toolbox / Package:

```
A = rand(3,4); % example data
maxdiff = max(pdist(A.'));
```

Or, manually:

```
d = sum(bsxfun(@minus, A, permute(A, [1 3 2])).^2, 1);
maxdiff = sqrt(max(d(:)));
```

Comment: The first gives me an error. The second a wrong end value in the whole code :(

Comment: Then you need to give an example with input and desired output. It's hard to guess what you want